# agregar botón en la página principal de curso - moodle

Tags: php, moodle

tengo un curso en moodle, hasta aquí todo bien, el curso me esta funcionando completamente bien, pero ahora tengo como requerimiento agregar un botón que solo sea visible para ciertos roles y además que tenga un enlace configurable.

he intentado agregándolo en un recurso - página, de igual forma, creándolo de cero, pero no encuentro forma correcta de hacerlo.

He creado un bloque

```
<?php
    // se pueden incluir libreria propia 
    // require_once("$CFG->dirroot/blocks/boton_personalizado/lib.php");

    defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

    class block_btn_course_report extends block_base
    {

        public function init()
        {
            $this->title = get_string('btnCourseReport', 'btnCourseReport');
        }

        public function instance_allow_multiple()
        {
            return false;
        }

        function has_config()
        {
            return false;
        }

        public function get_content()
        {
            global $CFG, $COURSE, $USER, $DB;

            // si ya tengo contenido salimos
            if ($this->content !== NULL)
            {
                return $this->content;
            }

            $context = CONTEXT_COURSE::instance($COURSE->id);

            // si el usuario no tiene permiso no hacemos nada
            if (!has_capability('block/btnCourseReport:addinstance', $context))
            {
                return '';
            }

            $this->content = new stdClass;
            $this->content->footer = '';
            $this->content->icons = array();

            $this->content->text = 'Hola, soy el cuerpo del bloque <br>';
            $this->content->text .= ' puedo contener cualquier HTML <br>';
            $this->content->text .= ' enlaces, formularios, imagenes... <br>';

            return $this->content;
        }

    }

    ?>
```

y un archivo de version

```
<?php
// This file is part of Moodle - http://moodle.org/
//
// Moodle is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
// (at your option) any later version.
//
// Moodle is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
// along with Moodle.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/**
 * Version details.
 *
 * @package    blocks
 * @subpackage btnCourseReport
 * @copyright  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU GPL v3 or later
 */

$plugin->version = 2015092120;  // YYYYMMDDHH (year, month, day, 24-hr time)
$plugin->requires = 2010112400; // YYYYMMDDHH (This is the release version             
for Moodle 2.0)
$plugin->release = 3.3;
?>
```

aun no encuentro la forma de activar o instalar el bloque he creado en moodle, pero esa pregunta se esta desarrollando [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/221365/cono-instalar-y-activar-un-bloque-en-moodle?noredirect=1#comment412556_221365)

Aun necesito ayuda, quedo pendiente.

Comment: Estaría bien que indiques que versión de Moodle usas, quizá exista algún bloque que te sirva para la tarea.

Comment: version de moodle 3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma de conseguir "agregar botón en la página principal de curso" es **creando un bloque**.

https://docs.moodle.org/all/es/dev/Desarrollo_de_bloques

Básicamente necesitaras:

1. Crear la carpeta del bloque en la ruta  *raiz_moodle*/blocks  por
   ejemplo crearemos  `moodle/blocks/boton_personalizado`
2. Crear el fichero base del bloque, debe llamarse 
   *block_*nombre_del_bloque.php, en nuestro caso `block_boton_personalizado.php`. El contenido de ese fichero será la clase que se usará para instanciar el
   bloque.

> **OJO!!** No usar *camelCase* para los nombres, mejor *snake_case*, usar el
>   guión bajo para separar palabras.

Un ejemplo mínimo sería:

```
    // se pueden incluir libreria propia 
    // require_once("$CFG->dirroot/blocks/boton_personalizado/lib.php");

    defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

    class block_boton_personalizado extends block_base {

        public function init() {
            $this->title ='Titulo bloque';             }

        public function instance_allow_multiple() {
            return false;
        }

        function has_config() {
            return false;
        }

        public function get_content() {
            global $CFG, $COURSE, $USER, $DB;

            // si ya tengo contenido salimos
            if ($this->content !== NULL) {
                return $this->content;
            }

            $context = CONTEXT_COURSE::instance($COURSE->id);

            $this->content = new stdClass;
            $this->content->footer = '';
            $this->content->icons = array();

            $this->content->text = 'Hola, soy el cuerpo del bloque <br>';
            $this->content->text .= ' puedo contener cualquier HTML <br>';
            $this->content->text .= ' enlaces, formularios, imagenes... <br>';

            return $this->content;
        }    }
```

Como puedes observar en `get_content()` es donde debes escribir el contenido del bloque, será el método que se ejecute cuando toque pintar el bloque.

3. Crear un fichero llamado `version.php` donde se identifica la versión requerida de Moodle y la del propio bloque:

   ```
   <?php
   // This file is part of Moodle - http://moodle.org/
   //
   // Moodle is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
   // it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   // the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
   // (at your option) any later version.
   //
   // Moodle is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   // but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   // MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   // GNU General Public License for more details.
   //
   // You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
   // along with Moodle.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

   /**
    * Version details.
    *
    * @package    blocks
    * @subpackage btnCourseReport
    * @copyright  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    * @license    http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU GPL v3 or later
    */

   $plugin->version = 2015092120;  // YYYYMMDDHH (year, month, day, 24-hr time)
   $plugin->requires = 2010112400; // YYYYMMDDHH (This is the release version for Moodle 2.0)
   $plugin->release = 1.0;
   ?>
   ```
4. Ir a la Administración del sitio Moodle para instalar y activar el
   bloque.
5. Por último agregarlo en los cursos.

Esto es una explicación muy muy muy muy muy básica de como funciona un bloque, en cuanto empiezas a hacer uno es serio podrías meterte en líos de permisos (capabilities), fichero de instalación/actualización, creación de formularios moodle y un largo etcétera.

Como indicas que necesitas que sea visible para ciertos roles comentarte que eso no se realiza mediante los permisos (https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Access_API) pues estos son usados para saber quien puede ocultar , añadir o quitar el bloque.

Lo que tendrás que hacer es que el mencionado `get_content()` devuelva diferente contenido según el rol del usuario, mediante condicionales en su código.

Esta solución es válida para agregar funcionalidades a todos los cursos, si lo que necesitas es hacerlo en un solo curso o en unos pocos y en el cuerpo del mismo y no en el lateral de las herramientas, podrías **crear un nuevo formato de curso**, para esto:

1. Copiar la carpeta del formato que nos interese usar de base, por
   ejemplo `moodle/course/format/topics` y le llamaremos
   `moodle/course/format/topics_button`
2. Añadir el código necesario para realizar el botón antes o después de
   `if (!empty($displaysection))` según te interese que aparezca en la
   cabecera o en el pie del curso.
3. Ahora, al crear/editar el curso selecciona el formato que acabas de
   realizar (`topics_button`) y verás aparecer el contenido nuevo. Eso si, todos los cursos con ese formato tendrían el mismo contenido adicional, aunque esto podría ser parametrizado desde la configuración del curso.

Si lo que quieres el algo mucho más dinámico, que puedas añadir en cualquier parte del curso, ocultar o mostrar condicionalmente según características del curso y/o alumno (https://docs.moodle.org/all/es/Configuraciones_de_actividades_condicionales) lo que quizá te interese sería **crear un recurso personalizado** realizando algo parecido a lo comentado del formato de curso, copiar uno existente para usar como base, por ejemplo `moodle/mod/label`.

De todas formas, conviene buscar primero en el repositorio de Moodle si existe algún recurso, actividad, formato, bloque o plugin que realice todo o parte de lo que necesitamos, a menos que por alguna circunstancia deseemos programarlo nosotros mismos.

(edito)

**BLOQUE BÁSICO DESCARGABLE**

Desde la pagina oficial (en inglés) de desarrollo de bloques (https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks#Basic_Concepts) nos enlazan al repositorio de Daniel Neis Araujo's [NEWBLOCK template](https://github.com/danielneis/moodle-block_newblock) en Github.

Comment: Primero que todo, gracias, es dificil encontrar documentación tan detallada sobre los bloques y aunque lo intente encontraba error tras error, estoy intentando eso, pero no veo la forma de instalar y activar el bloque, el archivo ya se encuentra en la raíz, este no debería reconocerlo.. quedo pendiente, gracias.

Comment: Bueno, ya sabes como va esto... si te vale la respuesta aceptala y crea otra más específica, mostrando el código de lo que llevas hecho y explicando lo más detalladamente posible los problemas con que te encuentras.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta como me lo recomendaste, añadí las lineas nuevas que he obtenido, de igual forma sigo buscando en la documentación, muchas gracias

Comment: Nueva edición, dejo un enlace a un bloque "plantilla" cortesía de  Daniel Neis Araujo