# Cono instalar y activar un bloque en moodle

Tags: php, moodle

He creado un bloque en moodle en la carpeta siguiendo la anterior [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/221163/agregar-bot%C3%B3n-en-la-p%C3%A1gina-principal-de-curso-moodle/221170?noredirect=1#comment411626_221170)
he creado el bloque tal como lo dicen en la respuesta pero en el punto 4 y 5 donde dice.

1. Ir a la Administración del sitio Moodle para instalar y activar el bloque

No eh podido encontrar como activar el bloque desde la administración del curso, o como añadir el bloque para que me aparezca entre las opciones de bloques en moodle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He cambiado de igual forma la clase para que posea el mismo nombre del archivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en este caso ya deberia aparecerme como bloque, no?

Alguna idea?

Comment: Punto 2: Crear el fichero base del bloque, debe llamarse **block_nombre_del_bloque.php**, no puede llamarse btnCourseReport debe llamarse como he indicado, tanto el fichero como la clase. Es la forma por la cual Moodle puede detectar e instanciar nuevos addons, todos siguen la misma estructura.

Comment: Y el Punto 4 habla de la administración del sitio, no la administración del curso. Se parece pero no es lo mismo. Si todo va bien no hay que hacer nada ahí, solo verificar que esta instalado.

Comment: El fichero base se llama block_btnCourseReport.php, la clase tenia nombre diferente pero lo corregí y aparece con el mismo nombre tanto clase como fichero.

Comment: pero llego al mismo final, actualizare la pregunta para los nuevos cambios

Comment: ok pero, por favor, pon código escrito no capturas de pantalla, al menos para las partes de programación.

Comment: te remito a la pregunta original, donde he editado la respuesta con dos factores decisivos: crear fichero version.php y usar snake case en los nombres. Revísalo y me cuentas.

Comment: a la pregunta original voy a eliminar la imagen y añadiré el código de la clase actual que tengo y sus respectivas modificaciones en un futuro para que lo tengas en cuenta. A base, he revisado la pregunta original, y tengo el archivo de versión y lo he creado en la misma carpeta donde esta clase (tomando como ejemplos los otros bloques que vienen en moodle)

cambie el nombre de la clase como el nombre del archivo para que fuera Snake_Case.. quedo al tanto